# Заблокировать нажатие клавиш "windows" в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как заблокировать нажатие обеих клавиш windows в PyQt?

Comment: Тут больше не Qt вопрос, а к WinAPI

Comment: НЕТ НУЖНО ИМЕННО В Python и pyqt

Comment: Не нужно капсить. WinApi доступен для любого популярного языка программирования на Windows, включая питон. Кст, а блокировка кнопок хотите сделать для окна вашей программы на Qt или глобально?

Comment: На qt нужно но не знаю как помогите

Comment: Qt - библиотека для создания графического интерфейса (GUI), а теперь вопрос, как вы хотите средствами Qt заблокировать нажатие клавиш?

Comment: Ну а как тогда, мне нужно чтобы когда програма исполнялась, то при нажатие на кнопку windows нечего не происходило